# Next.js Serverless function using odoo works fine locally but not when deploying to vercel

Tags: next.js, odoo, vercel

I'm using odoo external API to create records, when testing on postman everythings works fine. But when i deployed on vercel and i started testing on supabase with a webhook it just doesnt cross the odoo scope it consoles the record from the request and it stops.

*logs*
[image]
*api/residences*

```
var Odoo = require("odoo-xmlrpc");
    export async function POST(req: Request) {
      const {record} = await req.json();
      console.log(record);
      
    
      var odoo = new Odoo({
        url: "http://159.223.227.196/",
        // port: <insert server Port (by default 80)>,
        db: "159.223.227.196",
        username: "admin",
        password: "admin",
      });
      // API KEY : b2618aa898366ea26e4c160031307871e7d7a87b
      // odoo.connect(function (err:any) {
      //   if (err) { return console.log(err); }
      //   console.log('Connected to Odoo server.');
      // });
      
      odoo.connect(function (err: any) {
        console.log("loading...");
    
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("Connected to Odoo server.");
    var params = [];
    params.push([{
      name:record.name,
      street:record.address,
      city:record.city
    }]);
    console.log(params);
    
    odoo.execute_kw(
      "res.company",
      "create",
      params,
      function (err: any, value: any) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("Result: ", value);
      }
    );
  });
  return new Response("company created succesfully!");
}
```